# Windows 10 Oauth2 issue AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp

Tags: java, servlets, oauth-2.0, windows-10

Sorry to bring this question up if was already answered but I have not find anything related in the archive here.

I have developed application witch feed data from one software automatically to google spreadsheet. To get user tokens for Google I use Oauth2.
So far this works well on Windows 7. 
But recently I've migrated to Windows 10 and when I run the same application I'm getting following output

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest     at
>   com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver.getRedirectUri(LocalServerReceiver.java:98)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:76)
>     at
>   oauthtest.DriveAuthentication.authorize(DriveAuthentication.java:99)
>     at
>   oauthtest.DriveAuthentication.getDriveService(DriveAuthentication.java:111)
>     at oauthtest.DriveAuthentication.main(DriveAuthentication.java:120)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     ... 5 more
>
> there is code nipple

Below is the code

```
public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in =
        DriveAuthentication.class.getResourceAsStream("client_secret.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
        GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
        flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    System.out.println(
            "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
    return credential;
}
```

Issue is pointed on line

```
Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
        flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
```

When I want 1st time authenticate user with application.
If I use credentials created on WIN7 they works for WIN10 w/o issue.

Thank you for any idea

Answer (score 0):

So finally I've find the cure for my problem. There was missing [servlet-api-2.5.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadservletapi25jar.htm). After adding this to my project it works as on WIN7